# Is there any Google Apps Script functional for reporting on Google Apps Script activity itself?

Tags: google-apps-script

For example, I'd like a daily email showing success/failed executions. Stuff like that. Is there any way to access data about Google Apps Script the platform from Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: Take a look at the Google Activity API which is actually part of the latest release of Drive API.  Just google for it

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*You can use the Apps Script API to get this information.*

#### More Information:

The Apps Script API provides a method which allows you to list information about processes. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes/list):

> List information about processes made by or on behalf of a user, such as process type and current status.

The `return` of this method contains the type of process and its status:

> #### Resource: Process
>
> Representation of a single script process execution that was started from the script editor, a trigger, an application, or using the Apps Script API. This is distinct from the Operation resource, which only represents executions started via the Apps Script API.
>
> ```js
> {
>  "projectName": string,
>  "functionName": string,
>  "processType": enum (ProcessType),
>  "processStatus": enum (ProcessStatus),
>  "userAccessLevel": enum (UserAccessLevel),
>  "startTime": string,
>  "duration": string
> }
> ```

Where:

- `projectName` is the name of the script being executed,
- `functionName1` is the name of the function that started the execution,
- `processType` is the [type of execution](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#ProcessType) such as Trigger-based or Time-driven,
- `processStatus` is the [status of the execution](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#ProcessStatus) - this has the failure information
- `userAccessLevel` is the [executing users access level](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#UserAccessLevel) to the script,
- `startTime` is the time at which the execution started
- `duration` is how long the execution went on for.

You can use this endpoint to get information related to your script executions, including failed executions.

#### References:

- [Method: processes.list | Apps Script API | Google Devlopers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes/list)
- [REST ResourceL processes | Apps Script API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes)